# Having trouble with opening files with Github Actions

Tags: python, github, github-actions

I create a python tool for processing points clouds and I also wrote some unit tests to be sure my new implemented features will not impact the others. I want to automate these tests executions by using Github Actions : when I push some changes on my repo, I want to start the tests.

So I wrote a python-test.yml file that set-up Python, install my dependencies and execute my test.py file. The problem is when the python test.py is executed, I get this error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/test.py", line 68, in <module>
    class TestDo(unittest.TestCase):
  File "src/test.py", line 69, in TestDo
    with open("../test/data/pipeline.json", "r") as p:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../test/data/pipeline.json'
```

I don't understand that because my pipeline.json file is well present in my /test/data folder :

```
.
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.rst
├── environment.yml
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── pdal_parallelizer
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __main__.py
│   │   ├── bounds.py
│   │   ├── cloud.py
│   │   ├── do.py
│   │   ├── file_manager.py
│   │   └── tile.py
│   └── test.py
└── test
    └── data
        ├── input
        │   ├── echantillon_10pts.laz
        │   ├── echantillon_10pts2.laz
        │   └── echantillon_10pts3.laz
        ├── output
        │   └── output.laz
        ├── pipeline.json
        └── temp
            ├── temp__echantillon_10pts.pickle
            ├── temp__temp_name.pickle
            └── temp_name.pickle
```

Did someone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong ?
Regards.

**EDIT :**

There is my python-test.yml file :

```
name: Use Setup-Miniconda From Marketplace To Run Tests
on: [push]

jobs:
  miniconda:
    name: Miniconda
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: conda-incubator/setup-miniconda@v2
        with:
          activate-environment: test
          environment-file: environment.yml
          python-version: 3.8
          auto-activate-base: false
      - shell: bash -l {0}
        run: |
          conda info
          conda list
      - name: Run tests
        shell: bash -l {0}
        run: |
          conda install pdal
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install dask distributed pdal
          python src/test.py
```

Comment: This would be easier to diagnose with a copy of your YAML file (or, better yet, a link to your repo) but it's probably because you are used to executing your tests from your `src/` dir (which you shouldn't) and the Action is executing your tests from the root of your repo (one level higher).

Comment: @FiddleStix I edit my topic and add my python-test.yml. My repo is : https://github.com/meldig/pdal-parallelizer if you want to look at it. So should I have to place my test.py file at the root of my repo ?

Comment: You would need to inform the `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE` as env variable in the step running the python test, and use this variable as reference in your python implementation (`os.getenv(ENV_VAR_NAME)`) to set the correct PATH to the file you need to open during the test.